# Custom backend link products tutorial

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, backend

I'm working on a module that will show a wizard on the frontend which ends up showing an advice on what products to buy after a couple questions.

To show an advice there will be a backend where i need to link products just like the cross-sells, upsells and related product tab on the edit product page. Does anyone know a tutorial i could follow to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you already tried? What have you accomplished? Did you experienced any problems?

Comment: I just got the backend working using tabs, so i have my form with basic settings. I just tried to copy the related product tab class as a tab in my own module but I am not sure how magento manages links in the database for the related products. I need to copy the setup to accomplish this.

Comment: I just found out that Magento uses the catalog_product_link for related products. I need to link from my own table to products. I guess i need to do a total new setup with my own grid.

Comment: Here's a tutorial i found on creating your own grid inside a tab: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid

Comment: This module creator will generate the code for your entity  and link your entity many to many with the products: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html

Comment: Guys, please post your solutions as answers. Not everyone reading all comments.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as said before, you should create your custom product link type with an installer. You could also assign linked attributes.

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

//insert link_type_id

$installer->run("INSERT INTO `{$this->getTable('catalog_product_link_type')}` (link_type_id,code) VALUES ('yourLinkTypeID','yourLinkTypeName')");

//insert linked attributes

$data = array(
   array(
       'link_type_id'                  => yourLinkTypeID,
       'product_link_attribute_code'   => 'something',
       'data_type'                     => 'text'
   ),
   array(
       'link_type_id'                  => yourLinkTypeID,
       'product_link_attribute_code'   => 'something',
       'data_type'                     => 'int'
   )
);

$installer->getConnection()->insertMultiple($installer->getTable('catalog/product_link_attribute'), $data);

$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

You will need to create your grid (you have the tutorial you mentioned at: http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-grid-serializer-admin-tabs-grid.)

In that grid you will need to load your collection with the linked attributes and save them. For that you will define a product type link model.

```
    <?php
class MyModule_Model_Product_Type_Link extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Link{


       public function useYourLinkTypeNameLinks()
       {
           $this->setLinkTypeId(yourLinkTypeID);
           return $this;
       }


       public function saveYourLinkTypeNameLinks($product)
       {
           $data = $product->getyourLinkTypeNameLinkData(yourLinkTypeID);
           if (!is_null($data)) {
               $this->_getResource()->saveProductLinks($product, $data,yourLinkTypeID);
           }
           return $this;
       }
    }
```

You can load your collection + the linked attributes in the grid (or somewhere else) by using

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('MyModule/product_type_link')->useyourLinkTypeNameLinks()
->getProductCollection()
->setProduct($this->_getProduct())
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Saving them would require you to get the serialized linkdata and save it trough:

```
MyModule_Model_Product_Type_Link->saveYourLinkTypeNameLinks($unserializedstuff)
```

You could also define const `LINK_TYPE_YOURLINKTYPENAME = yourLinkTypeID;` in the model so you could call it instead of having to add the number everywhere.

I hope it clarifies things a bit like this, i could give you the whole upsell like process but you can read that in the core :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking.
If you want to have an other many to many relation between products (just like cross-sells, up-sells and related) you can use [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html).  It does exactly that. Adds a new relation type called 'accessories'. You just can change the label.
If you want to link your own entity called 'advice' to the products, use [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/utilities/developer-tools/ultimate-modulecreator-8949.html) to create the code. It will generate the code you need for your entity and has the possibility to link your entity to the products.

Comment: this extension looks interesting, is there any list off posibilities available?

Comment: which one of them?

Comment: oh right sry the ultimate module creator

Comment: There is a documentation here (work in progress): http://tzyganu.github.io/moduleCreator/docs.html and some release notes here: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/p/ultimate-module-creator.html

Comment: Thx, will take a good look